# Контрольная сумма CRC16 на GPS трекере

Tags: crc

**Устройство:** GPS трекер Teltonika FMB125

Прибор устанавливает tcp соединение с сервером, и в него можно отправить команды на исполнение, преобразовав все это в байты.

Отправляю команду в socket - setparam 1000:600 (установить параметр Socket open timeout равным 600 сек.):

```
DUMP DATA START:
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 19 0C 01 05 00 00 00 11 73 65 74 70 61 72 61 6D 20 31 30 32 30 35 3A 36 30 01 00 00 CA B6 
DUMP DATA END

[2004.01.01 01:00:54]-[NETWORK.PARSER]  expecting rec nod response, but packet len: 37 != 4, presuming this is gprs cmd
[2004.01.01 01:00:54]-[GPRS.CMD]    CID: 12, NOD: 1, CMD: 5, data len: 17, CRC: CAB6
[2004.01.01 01:00:54]-[GPRS.CMD]    Invalid packet crc detected! Rec: 0xCAB6 != calc 0x8ABA. Packet parsing aborted
```

Последние 4 байта это CRC16/USB. 
Однако судя по логу трекер расчитал совсем другое: **0x8ABA**

Подскажите как трекер рассчитал эту контрольную сумму? Я не смог определить ни алгоритм расчета, ни массив байт...

Так же я отправляю команду: **setdigout 00**, **setdigout 10** (установить лог. ноль/единицу на выходе **dout1** для реле). И тут все отлично. Команда срабатывает, crc совпадают.

Код который преобразует данные в байты и рассчитывает CRC16/USB ровно тот же.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался в чем причина.

Так как у меня нет мануалов и описания протокола отправки команд на трекер, мне пришлось экспериментировать и спрашивать у гугла. 
Я нашел реализацию на github, подсмотрел там алгоритм расчета CRC-16. 
Отправив байты в трекер, команда была исполнена и был сделан вывод что моя реализация правильная и зря. Возможно crc просто совпали, что странно, не знаю.

А вот как надо делать.

Алгоритм расчета: **CRC-16/ARC**

Первые 8 байт пропускаем. Считаем CRC-16 только у того что внутри { }

Команда "**setparam 1000:600**"

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 19 { 0C 01 05 00 00 00 11 73 65 74 70 61 72 61 6D 20 31 30 32 30 35 3A 36 30 01 } 00 00 8A BA
```

CRC16: **0x8ABA**